# Power functions that are Gram-Schmidt orthogonalized vs Legendre polynomials

Tags: linear-algebra

I have the following power functions:

```
{1, t, t^2}
```

After orthogonalizing them using Gram-Schmidt I obtained the following set which is orthogonal.

```
{1/Sqrt(2), Sqrt(3/2) t, Sqrt(5/2) (3 t^2 - 1)}
```

I then used Mathematica to observe the first three elements of the Legendre polynomials, and they were as follow

```
{1, t, (-1 + 3*t^2)/2}
```

How can I deduce the relationship that these two outputs have in common. I understand that the orthogonalized GS has factors {1/Sqrt(2), Sqrt(3/2)...} when compared to Legendre polynomials. Is this the relationship? Also how does this relationship enable the fact that the dot product of each element of the Legendre polynomial in a function space will be equal to 0.

Comment: When working with an inner product space, it is good practice to specify the inner product. Here it is $\langle f, g \rangle = \int_{-1}^{1} f(x) g(x) dx.$ The second subset of polynomials is also normalized, so they are orthonormal. Lastly, multiply $t^{2} - \frac{1}{3},$ which you obtain from the Gram-Schmidt orthogonalization process, and obtain $\frac{3t^{2} - 1}{2}.$ Then, you will see how to connect the result of the Gram-Schmidt orthogonalization process with the output from Mathematica.

Answer (score 1):

The normalized Legendre polynomials are
$$
       P_n(x)= \sqrt{n+\frac{1}{2}}\frac{d^n}{dx^n}(1-x^2)^n,n=0,1,2,3,\cdots.
$$
These are real, bounded solutions of
$$
                  ((1-x^2)y')' = \lambda y,\;\;\; \int_{-1}^{1}y(x)^2dx=1.
$$
Any other real, bounded, normalized solution is $\pm 1$ times one of these.
The solution $P_n$ corresponds to $\lambda=n(n+1)$. None of the solutions for any other $\lambda\in\mathbb{C}$ are bounded on $(-1,1)$.